# How to copy the data file from client azure Blob to local blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, talend

How to copy the data file from client azure Blob to local blob storage.

Comment: You want to copy files from an Azure Blob storage to your local storage emulator? Please reconsider your used tags, I don't see them related to your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) to accomplish that:

```
AzCopy https://nameofblob.blob.core.windows.net/containername /dest:c:\yourlocalfolder /sourcekey:”container access key” /s
```

The /s switch copies the directory structure.